# Embedding Kestrel inside WinForm application .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rest, kestrel

I'm struggling at embedding kestrel inside a WinForm application using .NET 6. I've found many examples about that but with older .NET version and as I know the migration from .NET 5 to 6 has a lot of breaking changes. The Microsoft documentation, in my opinion is more confusing than helping, expecially from my previous Java experience.
What I need is a simple webserver embedded in winform application configured to answer to a couple of rest endpoints. That is.

Used this https://jason-ge.medium.com/host-kestrel-web-server-in-net-6-windows-form-application-8b0fd70b4288 as starting point but it's lacking a downloadble example and many classes have no reference and thus, it won't compile.

Thank you very much.

Edit: Some code...I've made it to run but I don't know if it's good:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
 {
     Task.Run(() => StartWebServer());
     Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
     Form = new MainForm();
     Application.Run(Form);
 }

 private static void StartWebServer()
 {
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
     builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
     builder.WebHost.UseKestrel().ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
     {
         serverOptions.ListenLocalhost(80);
     });
     var app = builder.Build();
     app.MapGet("/{id}", (int id, [FromHeader(Name = "X-SIGN-DOCUMENT")] string document) =>
         {
             return "Hello " + id + " doc = [" + document + "]";
         }
     );
     app.Run();
}
```

I've also the Startup class but I don't know if it's used.
It is good? Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show, what you tried so far and add a specific question/error to your post.

Comment: Edited with now running code...I don't know if it follows best practices or not. Thank you.

Comment: So you actually have running code? What is the concrete question?

Comment: I've tried all the day to made it run...finally it runs..but...I've managed to do things right? Do I need the `Startup` class? Is there a better way to do service class? Endpoints with dependency injection? Thank you

Comment: You don't need `Task.Run`. You can use `app.RunAsync` or `app.StartAsync` to start the web app asynchronously, and stop it after `Application.Run` returns. In .NET 6 and later `Startup` isn't used, all the configuration is done on the Builder object.

Comment: Excellent...thank you Panagiotis...Just another one...if I want to keep my delegate code `(int id, [FromHeader(Name = "X-SIGN-DOCUMENT")] string document) =>
         {
             return "Hello " + id + " doc = [" + document + "]";
         }` inside an external class...how the declaration is made? Thank you!